# Stuck implementing k means for big and small dogs - dodgy results

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, unsupervised-learning

my algortithm isnt working. The code seems to make sense and everything but im just not convinced with the results. I fell like the centroids should be amongst the data more, sort of central, but they arent doing that no matter how many iterations i set the algorithm too. Could someone run my code and give me some pointers? Ive labeled the code so you can understand it.
Some main points:

- k = 2; 2 centroids
- centroid1 = Dark red, so datapoints in this cluster are light red
- centroid 2 = Dark green, so datapoints in this cluster are light green
- dogs are either 'big' or 'small' depending on their height and weight
- The euclidean distance is used to decide on which cluster to belong to
- Raw/main data stored in dictionary labeled 'x'; they are moved about into the dictionaries 'cluster1' and 'cluster2' depending on their distance to the centroids

code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random, math

plt.title("Big Dogs and Small Dogs")
plt.ylabel("Height (cm)")
plt.xlabel("Weight (kg)")

def euclideandis(x, y, a, b):   # Formula for euclidean distance
    return math.sqrt((x-a)**2 + (x-a)**2)

x = {4.4:31,
     3.2:19,
     4.6:32,        # Data- key = weight, value = height
     4:25,
     4.1:29,
     2.90:17,
     2.9:11}

centroid1 = [[random.uniform(min(x.keys()), max(x.keys())), random.uniform(max(x.values()), min(x.values()))]]   # create random centroids that are between the datapoints
centroid2 = [[random.uniform(min(x.keys()), max(x.keys())), random.uniform(max(x.values()), min(x.values()))]]

for j in xrange(1):   # keep updating colours, position of centroids
    cluster1 = {}       # Everything in cluster 1 is closest to the dark red spot, therefore gets included in this dict, and gets scattered in light red
    cluster2 = {}       # Everything in cluster 2 is closest to the dark green spot, therefore gets included in this dict, and gets scattered in light green
    for key in x:
        temp1 = 0       # works out euclidean distance for all data points in x, then compares them
        temp2 = 0
        temp1 = euclideandis(key, x[key], centroid1[0][0], centroid1[0][1]) # Dis betw data point, red centroid
        temp2 = euclideandis(key, x[key], centroid2[0][0], centroid2[0][1]) # Dis betw data point, green centroid
        if temp1 < temp2:
            cluster1[key] = x[key]      # if the euclidean distance between datapoint and red spot,
                                        # smaller than the euclidean distance between datapoint and green spot,
                                        # add the point to the red cluster, else add to green cluster
        else:
            cluster2[key] = x[key]

    centroid1 = [[0, 0]]        # Centroids reset as they will be changed  
    centroid2 = [[0, 0]]

    iterable = 0
    for key in cluster1:        # works out mean coordinates of each cluster and changes the centroids coordinates to this
        iterable = iterable + key
    centroid1[0][0] = iterable/len(cluster1)
    iterable = 0
    for key in cluster1:
        iterable = iterable + cluster1[key]
    centroid1[0][1] = iterable/len(cluster1)
    iterable = 0
    for key in cluster2:
        iterable = iterable + key
    centroid2[0][0] = iterable/len(cluster2)
    iterable = 0
    for key in cluster2:
        iterable = iterable + cluster2[key]
    centroid2[0][1] = iterable/len(cluster2)



plt.scatter(cluster1.keys(), cluster1.values(), color = "red")      # scatters everythning
plt.scatter(cluster2.keys(), cluster2.values(), color = "lime")
plt.scatter(centroid1[0][0], centroid1[0][1], color = "maroon") 
plt.scatter(centroid2[0][0], centroid1[0][1], color = "green")
plt.show()
```

To sum up, there isn't a clear error with my program, only I'm not really convinced about the results

[image: The plot after 100k iterations; shouldn't the centroids be more in the middle of the datapoints?]

(above) why after 100k iterations arent the centroids in the middle of the datapoints? The red one is but the green one isnt

Comment: How about showing the plot?

Comment: done. added above @CalZ

Answer (score 3):

The centroid is likely correct, you have a display error

The line

```
plt.scatter(centroid2[0][0], centroid1[0][1], color = "green")
```

should be

```
plt.scatter(centroid2[0][0], centroid2[0][1], color = "green")
```

That's just one of those things that happens when you implement an algorithm from scratch in order to learn it . . . I bet you've spent hours looking at the top part of your script :-)

Comment: Hahaha thank you very much. Sometimes all it is is Just an annoying little bug